# Prevent second monitor to "move" while in fullscreen games

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, fullscreen

I have two monitors. Sometimes I like to watch a movie or have a webpage or manual up on the second why I play a game on the primary.

Problem is that when I start some games, the content of the second monitor seems to be pushed around. It's very annoying. Doesn't happen in all games and I can't quite figure out what does it. Do any of you know? And more importantly, is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Related on Arqade: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170795/is-it-possible-to-have-a-second-monitor-that-is-unaffected-by-fullscreen-games-o

Comment: This only happens to me on Windows, on MacOS it seems fine (even tho the monitor res is changing, the windows do not get resized.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because of the resolution of the game. If the game resolution doesn't match the normal resolution you use outside of the game, the resolution will change and cause strange effects on the other monitors. This works from left to right, so if you play the game on your right-most monitor, you will never experience this.

The solution is to play the game in the same resolution that you use normally for your monitor, or to run the game in a window so that the monitor resolution need not be changed.

Comment: So another reason to upgrade my graphics card then I suppose :p

Comment: This hits hard in 2022 with a new 4k monitor a GFX card shortage : (

Answer (score 0):

This used to happen to me. How I got around this is by making it ignore the scaling set by games.

To do this go to your graphics control panel (nvidia control panel). Go to "Adjust desktop size and position" and under  "scaling" there is sometimes a checkmark box option to "override the scaling mode set by games and programs".

This worked for me.